# Forcefully update a label value outside a call back area

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, callback, devexpress

I am using devexpress scheduler in my asp.net application. My scheduler contains date navigator and view navigator (mainly, day view, week view and month view). My scheduler is inside a user control. I use this user control in my aspx page. In this page, I have a label `lblRecords` that shows the number of records showing in the scheduler. When I change the view (default view is month view), the label does not get updated. Below are some images that shows  my problem.

When loading page in month view 139 records
[image]

In this case, I have changed the view to day view and there is only 1 record. But the label still shows 139.

[image]

**Aspx page**

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updCalendar" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="leftarea" style="height: 400px">
                        <div class="comn_captn calender_left">
                            Calender View<a href="#"></a></div>
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">

                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: top">
                                    <label>
                                        <strong>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblRecords" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong></label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="vertical-align: top">
                                    <hr />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
    ....

                            </table>

                    </div>
                    <div class="rightarea">
                        <div class="comn_captn">
                            &nbsp;
                        </div>
                        <div class="comonform_elements">
                            <uc1:CalendarView ID="calBMJob" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
       </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In this code, `calBMJob` is the user control that contains the scheduler.

Please help me with this issue. I have tried many solutions in SO but nothing worked. Any work around would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that when you change the view a callback is happening on your schedule control. This callback does not contain the label so if you update the label text on the server the changes will not be visible on the client. There are a few ways to get this to work.

1:
(probably more work)
Put everything in an ASPxCallbackPanel and set all controls begin callback clientside events to cancel event and then call the CallbackPanel.PerformCallback(args) method.

2:
(probably less work)
Update the label in the client side [EndCallback](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxSchedulerScriptsASPxClientScheduler_EndCallbacktopic) method of the schedule control with a value from a [JSProperty](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_JSPropertiestopic) something like so:

```
//javascript
function CalendarView_EndCallback(s,e){
   if(s.cp_labelText != undefined)
   {
      //change label to ASPxLabel and set a JSProperty on schedule control to do this.
      lblRecords.SetText(s.cp_labelText);
   }
}
```

This would mean that you need a property on your UserControl to set the EndCallback method on the page that creates the control and a property to gain access to the JSProperty or a control that has the JSProperty.

Comment: I shall try it out and let you know